# how to remove duplicate jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am working with ajax to get data, i am loading jquery in that, So if i will hit ajax 3 times then it will load jquery 3 times, I need to remove duplicate jquery, So what i need to do ? Can anyone have solution for this ? Is there any jquery hack so i can remove that jquery.Please give me some solution so i can resolve this issue. Any help will be really appreciated. 
I am loading jquery in view file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/js/ajax.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/js/jquery.yiigridview.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to remove it

Comment: We have no idea how your ajax works or how duplicates are determined. There isn't enough information provided to help with